# Proposing tag synonym: [big-o] and friends → [complexity]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I propose that the tags [big-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-o) [big-omega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-omega) [little-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/little-o) [big-theta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-theta) be made synonyms for [complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complexity), as it is unlikely that a question needs expertise specific to big-O or whichever, rather than complexity in general.

I note [this previous request for it to be made possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108122/can-the-big-o-complexity-synonym-suggestion-be-reversed), but since [user Foo Bah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590042/foo-bah) hasn't been active in a year I assume they will not be proposing the synonym (and I don't have nor expect to have soon the tag score to do it myself).

Answer (score 6):

Since they deal with asymptotic complexity, and we already have a [asymptotic-complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asymptotic-complexity) tag, why not synonymify all of them to [asymptotic-complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asymptotic-complexity) instead? Whether or not [complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complexity) should be a synonym of [asymptotic-complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asymptotic-complexity) is debatable (as far as I can tell, they mean the same in the context of programming)

Comment: I wasn't aware of [tag:asymptotic-complexity]; my original observation was when I saw a post tagged [tag:complexity] edited to add [tag:big-o] and I thought that seemed unnecessary. [tag:complexity] seems to be 10× more popular than [tag:asymptotic-complexity] and not particularly different in content, FWIW.

Comment: @KevinReid: Exactly. Generally, synonyming to a more specific tag name is better (it prevents ambiguities that may crop up)