# Should this be a tag synonym? [big-o] and [big-omega]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

I noticed [big-omega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-omega) has 6 uses and a stub description that is a synonym for [big-o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-o) which has a full fleshed out description.  I don't have any privileges regarding tags yet, so I thought I'd mention it here.

Comment: I think this is a much better synonymization: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251548/proposing-tag-synonym-big-o-and-friends-%e2%86%92-complexity complexity <-- big-*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, [big-omega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-omega) *and* [big-theta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-theta) should have better tag wiki content.<sup>1</sup>

And note that one would expect their usage to be significantly less: only used with the most rigorous analysis of algorithmic complexity.

---

<sup>1</sup> My CS knowledge is not really up to a useful expansion.

Answer (score 9):

Revising my position.

No, [big-omega](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-omega) should **not** be a synonym. Big-Omega is a *different notation*; see the [Family of Bachmann–Landau notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) on Wikipedia. There is another related tag here: [big-theta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/big-theta).

The terms are related, but not synonymous. The wiki perhaps needs to be updated to reflect the relationship.

I've erroneously [proposed a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/big-o/synonyms) for this; I'd like people to vote *against* this request.

Comment: Will CS people read the tag description and use the right precise tag, or use the wrong one or a commonly-used one?  My experience is that questioners are not always up on formal nomenclature, to the point of that being part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The current big-omega wiki is not just short, it is incorrect. The various complexity notations describe the growth of some function in terms of the growth of another function as their argument tends to infinity. The function whose growth is being described may itself be worst case time, best case time etc.

The issue is complicated by the fact of alternative definitions, but for SO the Knuth definition is the more relevant. The Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation covers all this well. Maybe copy some material from there, with attribution?

Comment: Yes, if the tag description made the difference very clear, it would be different.  But as stated it's imprecise.  I think people would not make such a fine distinction when tagging, and a single tag for complexity of algorithms is proper.  Or, would people interested in the subject know to subscribe to every form separately or end up missing the rare but specific ones?